# How to increase heap size for jBoss server

Tags: java, jboss, out-of-memory

I have an upload files scenario in my project.  When I'm trying to upload the large files it's giving me an OutOfMemory error.  That error is related to Java heap size.

How can you increase the heap size in Java and which file do I need to alter for this?  I'm using jboss 5.1 server for running my application.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java

Answer (score 34):

You can set it as JVM arguments the usual way, e.g. `-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m` for a minimum heap of 1GB and maximum heap of 2GB. JBoss will use the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable to include additional JVM arguments, you could specify it in the `/bin/run.conf.bat` file:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"
```

However, this is more a **workaround** than a real solution. If multiple users concurrently uploads big files, you'll hit the same problem sooner or later. You would need to keep increasing memory for nothing. You should rather configure your file upload parser to store the uploaded file on temp disk instead of entirely in memory. As long as it's unclear which parser you're using, no suitable answer can be given. However, more than often Apache Commons FileUpload is used under the covers, you should then read the documentation with "threshold size" as keyword to configure the memory limit for uploaded files. When the file size is beyond the threshold, it would then be written to disk.

Comment: +1. The advice _not_ to store the whole file in memory is good.

Answer (score 8):

On wildfly 8 and later, go to `/bin/standalone.conf` and put your JAVA_OPTS there, with all you need.

Answer (score 6):

Edit the following entry in the run.conf file.  But if you have multiple JVMs running on the same JBoss, you might want to run it via command line argument of -Xms2g -Xmx4g (or whatever your preferred start/max memory settings are.

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
```

Answer (score 6):

I have mentioned the configuration changes needed for the **increase of heap size** in **Windows** or **Linux** environments.

**Linux**:

```
bin/standalone.conf
```

Check for the following line,

```
JAVA_OPTS
```

and change it accordingly to suit your **heap size needs**

```
-Xms1303m: initial heap size in megabytes
-Xmx1303m: maximum heap size in megabytes

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048M"
```

**Windows**:

```
bin/standalone.conf.bat

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048M"
```

Now **restart** the server and it will work without prompting any heap size errors.

For more information you can refer this link below.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/getting_started_guide/adjust_memory_settings

Answer (score 5):

Use -Xms and -Xmx command line options when runing java:

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
```

For more help type `java -X` in command line.

Answer (score 3):

Look in your JBoss bin folder for the file run.bat (run.sh on Unix)

look for the line 
`set JAVA_OPTS`, (or just JAVA_OPTS on Unix) at the end of that line add -Xmx512m. Change the number to the amount of memory you want to allocate to JBoss.

If you are using a custom script to start your jboss instance, you can add the set JAVA_OPTS option there as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, for `jboss 6.3` I had to change `JAVA_OPTS` in file `jboss-eap-6.3\bin\standalone.conf.bat` and set following values `-Xmx8g -Xms8g -Xmn3080m` for  jvm to take 8gb space.

Comment: Also add for Jboss-eap-7.1

Answer (score 0):

What to change?

> set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"

Where to change? (Normally)

> bin/standalone.conf(Linux) standalone.conf.bat(Windows)

What if you are using custom script which overrides the existing settings? then?

> setAppServerEnvironment.cmd/.sh (kind of file name will be there)

More information are already provided by one of our committee members!
[BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc).

Answer (score 0):

Add following option in jboss in bin/standalone.conf.bat

```
   set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase or set the heap size configuration i.e. -`Xms`/`Xmx` or any other `JVM` options in the `JBoss` application server in `JAVA_OPTS` `JVM` options in `standalone.conf(Linux)` & `standalone.conf.bat` file in Windows.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M"
```