# Reading file .xlsx very large in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm working on a web application using Java, where I have a method that should read a **.xlsx** file using **apache-poi**:

```
public static void xlsx(String arquivo) throws IOException{

     try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(arquivo));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell celula = cellIterator.next();
                /*here do the reading for each cell,*/
            }
        }
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException("Erro ao processar arquivo.",e.getCause());
    }
}
```

The method works correctly, however how likely this method will process files with thousands of lines of records, for example, about 25-300 thousand lines. When processing a large file I take the following exception:

```
(http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) Servlet.service() for servlet RestServlet threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I need to know how can I avoid this type of error. If you have for example, read and process the file **.xlsx** 1000 to 1000 lines, or some other solution.

Comment: Did you try the [Apache POI SAX interface for .xlsx files](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)? From the [docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) `If memory footprint is an issue, then for XSSF, you can get at the underlying XML data, and process it yourself`

Comment: thanks for help @Gagravarr, I will make these changes.

Comment: I know that the developer doesn't often get a lot of input into the process, but it needs to be said:  a 300k line spreadsheet should be transitioned into a database ASAP.

Comment: thanks for help @Gus but I don't know "database ASAP". you have any  reference, aboaut database ASAP for me?

Comment: ASAP is an acronym meaning "As Soon As Possible".

Comment: thanks for help dude. @Gus, you have any idea that I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep existing implementation, simply increase JVM maximum heap size.
Please see [How to increase heap size for jBoss server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252914/how-to-increase-the-jvm-size-in-java-and-which-file-i-need-to-alter-for-this) for instructions and a related discussion.

Comment: Thanks for help @VasylTrtiakov, but another problem I have is that my development machine is low on memory. Only 4gb.

Comment: Then you may want to consider processing that large spreadsheet in parts saving intermediate results in some place (file, database, etc.) if that approach is applicable to your processing algorithm.