# how to increase jboss memory heap size in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, heap-memory

I have tried to increase the java memory heap size for jboss by making changes to the `run.conf.bat` file as suggested from

[How to increase heap size for jBoss server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252914/how-to-increase-the-jvm-size-in-java-and-which-file-i-need-to-alter-for-this#answer-6252978)

and set to

```
    rem # JVM memory allocation pool parameters - modify as appropriate.
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M"
```

If I run the jboss server from the jboss_dir/bin directory using windows command prompt it runs with above `JAVA_OPTS` values

however if run the same jboss from `eclipse IDE` the `eclipse console` shows following message

```
    22:31:46,457 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_31,Sun Microsystems Inc.
22:31:46,457 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b05)
22:31:46,457 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.6-b01,Sun Microsystems Inc.
22:31:46,457 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,amd64
22:31:46,458 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
22:31:46,483 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
22:31:47,761 INFO  [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Loading profile: ProfileKey@4fe2fe5d[domain=default, server=default, name=default]
```

I was wondering what eclipse configuration I may have missed so that the jboss is still starting with the `JAVA_OPTS` with values `-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

```
22:31:46,458 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
```

Comment: Make sure that Eclipse is running your JBoss directly from JBoss folder and not from the auto generated eclipse configuration.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Server Runtime Environments have JBoss set to the configured JBoss folder (same folder from where I am manually running jboss from command prompt).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the servers tab, double clicking on a server opens a window called "Overview" (first image), where you can find sections like General Information, Management Login Credentials, Publishing, etc.

There's also a link "Open Launch Configurations", which opens a new window (second image) where you can set up vm arguments.

[image: Double clicking shows this]

[image: Open Launch COnfigurations shows this]